Cluster-level cache for storing REST service responses with synchronization
I know this is not very specific, but I'd be grateful for any suggestions.
According to the system admin guide, ClaimCenter is fully leveraging the caching mechanism if a user returns to the same server instance across different HTTP requests, but it requires the load balancer to always direct requests to the same ClaimCenter server, and only this enables true horizontal scalability.
Is it possible to configure a cluster-level cache for temporarily storing REST service responses and make it fully-synchronized? That is, is it possible to define a global cache to be used by all servers in a cluster and have the servers broadcasting all new responses to other cluster members immediately after they are computed?
If not, would an instance-specific cache of type LoadingCache<K,V> be enough?

What you are describing in your second paragraph is what ClaimCenter is doing.  It used to actually broadcast across the network every few seconds.  Now it updates a database table of the nodes updated since the last broadcast.  The issue is network traffic and timing.  It is not possible to do this in real time due to network latency.   There are some caching tools, but as soon as you get outside of the cluster you introduce other complexities.

I believe that the caching that each individual node (server) does is only caching the entity beans retrieved from the DB, not the REST responses. Each node has a cache of beans that are either evicted when that bean is updated (by any node, there is communication between the nodes to evict beans when one node updates an entity) or after about 30 minutes when the bean becomes stale (I think the time is configurable).
I have seen this question a couple of times in the past at clients and the problem is usually that a ClaimCenter portal is calling a ClaimCenter REST API. One of two things usually happens:

The load balancer does not have sticky session enabled so each call to the API goes to a random node which may not have previously loaded beans in the cache because the previous API call went to a different node
The load balancer has sticky session enabled, but it can only see the integration user used by the portal to call the ClaimCenter REST API (The load balancer can't see the portal user credential). This results in every call from the portal being directed to one node by the load balancer. This is also not ideal as it could overload the single node.

The solution is usually to enable sticky session on the load balancer and ensure the traffic is being split according to the portal user credential, not the integration user that is used to authenticate between the portal and ClaimCenter.
I think it is certainly possible to create a global cache of some sort that stores REST responses, but I would not recommend it. It is almost certainly something Guidewire would mark as non-conformant and technical debt.
Hope this helps, if anything isn't applicable to your situation then update your question and I would be happy to update my answer.

I should also add that storing the REST API responses in a cache seems simple, but opens up a bunch of concurrency issues. What if the entity (or entities) that the JSON response pulls data from is updated? Are you then going to search every node's cache for API responses that are invalid and evict those responses? That would seem like a very inefficient add-on to every single bundle transaction for ClaimCenter. It is definitely best to setup your load balancer to be able to direct API calls in the most efficient way to take advantage of the OOTB entity caching.

This all makes sense, but does it apply to row queries as well?

Ah yes row queries would not be stored in the application cache. See this documentation (https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1023/integration/integration/topics/querybuilderapi/c_ba2913624.html). What is this API that is causing performance issues actually doing? Is it an API that performs a search based on some input criteria? In the past I have had to return a "to many results" error back to the consuming application and force the portal devs to display a message indicating that too many results were returned. Happy to try to help if you can provide more details.

In essence, the API is intended to allow the consuming system access to claim data, but the results are to be paged (think of more). The problem is that some of the search criteria cannot really be interpreted as-is because the external system is the same system that I mentioned here. That is, the two systems use quite different data models, and it really complicates the query.

Right I think I understand. Is the consuming application calling the ClaimCenter API every time the next "page" of results are requested by the user? It would probably be best to get the full results from the ClaimCenter API and then store the results in the consuming application's memory so that when the next page of results is requested there is not another call to ClaimCenter. Also, I realize this is off topic, but there should also probably be a discussion about how to sunset the older claims systems. It seems the IT org is spending a lot of resources to keep these older systems running

Yes, every page is retrieved via a separate call to the service.

If you are writing a 'chatty' API, it is recommended by Guidewire to utilize session affinity or sticky sessions in order to increase the effectiveness of the database cache.  Guidewire Cloud, already does this for the portals.
In fact if you are doing updates to related entities and you don't enable sticky sessions you will likely have concurrent data change exceptions since the database cache updates are not instantaneous.

Thank you, but this is a self-managed implementation. Sorry I didn't mention it in the question.

Also, I think concurrency isn't an issue here because the handler never updates any entities.
